# Reddit OAuth2 User Authentication

Tags: javascript, http, post, cors, reddit

I am working on a web app which requires a user to login to their reddit account and according to https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#retrieving-the-access-token I need to send a POST request to https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token with some parameters. I am currently running the server from `localhost` and I keep getting the error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with this same issue and figured out that I need to register my app as "Installed" instead of "Web". This will make the authorization redirect with the bearer token instead of the code.

http://wattydev.com/authenticating_a_js-based_reddit_application_with_user_login_%28implicit_grant_flow%29